# How do I change the Google search domain in Chrome's New Tab page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I recently moved from Austria to Germany, but my Chrome (v35 beta) still searches in Google Österreich (meaning, `google.at`), rather than Google Germany (`google.de`).

[image]

I already went to Chrome's settings and changed my search provider to `google.de`:

[image]

However, it keeps reverting back to `google.at` when I restart the browser. Even after I do the change, the New Tab page shows me the old search domain.

Are there any other methods or ways to change the default domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it worked for me was to repeatedly enter random searches in the Omnibox (I think it was when I searched for Google) until Chrome asked me:

> Would you like to switch to google.de (…)?

After accepting that, my search domain changed to the right one.